# Scaffolding complex data models in ASP.NET Core MVC using Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-scaffolding

I am using scaffolding engine to generate boilerplate code in my ASP.NET CORE MVC project using Entity Framework.

When the data model is simple like below:

```
public class PersonalData: BaseEntity
{
    [Required]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Surname{ get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Required]
    public DateTime BirthDate{ get; set; } = new DateTime();
}
```

everything is ok, all fields are correctly generated in model, view and controller. These fields are of basic data types (string, DateTime, etc).

But when my data model contains custom data type as below:

```
public class PersonalData: BaseEntity
{
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Surname{ get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Required]
    public DateTime BirthDate{ get; set; } = new DateTime();
    [Required]
    public Document Doc { get; set; }
}
```

Where Document is a class with the following definition:

```
public class Document: BaseEntity
{
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string DocType{ get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Required]
    public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; } = new DateTime();
}
```

With the Document property in PersonalData the scaffolding system is not generating it's properties when scaffolding with PersonalData data model.

Is there is a way to do that or I am missing something ?

Thanks,
HPS.

Comment: As you mentioned, scaffolding engine does not help generate field(s) for complex type child property by default, if possible, you can modify the generated code to add fields based on your `Document` model class.

Comment: Thanks, so we will add Document filed(s) manually.